# Error: AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'Clear' in Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting this error while trying to run the below code in a demo site:

> ```
> self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='txtUsername']").Clear() 
> "AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'Clear'"
> ```

I create a POM format with 2 .py files but I can't get the root cause of the error.

This is the main class:

```
import time
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from POMProjectDemo.Pages.LoginPage import LoginPage
from POMProjectDemo.Pages.HomePage import HomePage

class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        s = Service("C:/drivers/chromedriver.exe")
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        cls.driver.maximize_window()

    def test_login_valid(self):
        driver = self.driver
        self.driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/index.php/auth/login")

        login = LoginPage(driver)
        login.enter_username("Admin")
        login.enter_password("admin123")
        login.click_login()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.close()
        cls.driver.quit()
        print("Test Completed")
```

This is the LoginPage:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class LoginPage:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

        self.username_textbox_xpath = "//input[@id='txtUsername']"
        self.password_textbox_cssSelector = "input[type='password']"
        self.login_button_xpath = "//input[@value='LOGIN']"

    def enter_username(self, username):
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, self.username_textbox_xpath).Clear()
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, self.username_textbox_xpath).send_keys(username)

    def enter_password(self, password):
        self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, self.password_textbox_cssSelector).Clear()
        self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, self.password_textbox_cssSelector).send_keys(password)

    def click_login(self):
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, self.login_button_xpath).Click()
```

Any thoughts on this error?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `.clear()` and `.click()`? I.e., both lowercase?

Answer (score 0):

These methods are **case sensitive**

**Wrong Case** : .Click() and .Clear() // which you have used instead use

**Correct Case** : **.click()** and **.clear()**

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice I was using uppercase in both, now its working successfully.